# How to create DateTime object from string in symfony2/php (Extended Question to the old one..)

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

Link: [How to create DateTime object from string in symfony2/php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750050/how-to-create-datetime-object-from-string-in-symfony2-php)

I am taking `date` from a form and passing all that data via a `form.serialize()` method with `ajax`. On the Symfony side, I am getting that value in `string` format. Now when I try to insert that data into database it was giving me an error as the type of that field was given `date`. So thanks to `@briosheje` I solved that thing.

But what if Now, sometimes I get `null` value from the form for that `date` value? Any idea, Anyone? Ohh, btw right now I have used `if($dateValue != null OR $dateValue != '')` condition.. any better solution then `if()` condition?

Answer (score 1):

If a date is optional and can be NULL in the database you can just do

```
$protocol->setStartedAt(null);
```

If not than the validation of your form (also with ajax!) should fail and the controller should return some JSON with a error message. You could do something like

```
{"success":false,"errors":[{"started_at":"Set this value!"}]}
```

And let javascript show the error(s).